# ./gradlew run adds other sourceSets as dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have two sourceSets: `main` and `annotations`

with sourceSets declaration

```
sourceSets {
    annotations {
        java.srcDirs = ["src/annotations"]
        java.outputDir = file("${buildDir}/annotations")
    }
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ["src/main"]
        java.outputDir = file("${buildDir}/main")
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.annotations.output
    }
}
```

sourceSets `main` depends on `annotations`. So I add dependencies this way:

```
run {
    classpath += sourceSets.annotations.output
}
```

But in this way, if I make any changes, `./gradlew run` has to run after `./gradlew build`, is there any better way to add source code (i.e. ***.java**) as dependencies?